# @Autowired Environment is always null

Tags: spring

I am having a simple `RestController`:

```
@RestController
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Word2VecRestController {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Word2VecRestController.class);

    // @Resource is not working as well
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    // This is working for some reason 
    // but it's null inside the constructor
    @Value("${test}") 
    String test;

    public Word2VecRestController() {

        LOGGER.info(env.getProperty("test"));

        System.out.println("");

    }

    @GetMapping("/dl4j/getWordVector")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Double[]>> getWordVector(String word) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

The problem is, that `env` is always `null`. I've seen somewhere that I could try to use `@Resource` instead of `@Autowired` but that didn't help.

**application.properties**:

```
test=helloworld
```

I've tried to use

```
@Value("${test}")
String test;
```

but the problem here is that these are `null` during construction of the object where I need it.

Comment: how are you creating object of `Word2VecRestController`?

Comment: @redflar3 This is done by the spring framework

Comment: your endpoint `/dl4j/getWordVector` is registered by spring?

Comment: @redflar3 Yes, that's working without troubles.

Comment: by any chance, it has to do with missing default constructor? else you can try removing the `@PropertySource`, just for testing

Comment: @redflar3 What should I see if I remove that? Missing default constructor? `Word2VecRestController` does define it?

Comment: @redflar3 Oh, could it be that this is always `null` in the constructor just as for anything declared with `@Value`?

Comment: sry, i wasn't clear, both are unrelated suggestions. by removing, you are letting spring use its intelligence to get the property file.

Comment: @redflar3 No, the property file was actually being found. I think it's my fault - it seems that this is `null` as well in the constructor.

Comment: @redflar3 Yep, it's `null` idk why I thought this would be initialized at that point ..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Field injection is done by Spring *after* the constructor is called. This is why `Environment` is null in the `Word2VecRestController` constructor. You can try constructor injection if you need it in the constructor:

```
@RestController
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Word2VecRestController {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Word2VecRestController.class);

    @Autowired
    public Word2VecRestController(Environment env, @Value("${test}") String test) {

        LOGGER.info(env.getProperty("test"));

        System.out.println("");

    }

    @GetMapping("/dl4j/getWordVector")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Double[]>> getWordVector(String word) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**PS**: if you use Spring Boot, you do not need the `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")`, this is automatically done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 @Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
 }
```

to enable the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to your configuration. Important this must been a `static` method!

For example:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SpringConfig {

     @Bean
     public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
     }

}
```